# Navigation Drawer animation is failing Espresso test

Tags: android-espresso

I'm testing changes to my NavigationDrawer via espresso. I open and close the drawer several times in a single test and I end up with this failing test:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed
>   because the target view does not match one or more of the following
>   constraints: at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to
>   the user.

The view in question is a view I am asserting against inside the drawer. I assume this is failing because Espresso is not idling for the drawer to open. I have all "animation scales" set to off in Developer options, but I see that the drawer sliding is not affected by this. Aside from creating a custom IdlingResouce, is there a built-in espresso function to tell it to wait?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `espressoContrib` library, then you should.
With function:

`onView(withId(R.id.drawerLayout))
            .perform(DrawerActions.open())
            .check(matches(DrawerMatchers.isOpen()))`

If you are, and still see that error, maybe [this](https://github.com/chiuki/espresso-samples/blob/master/idling-resource-elapsed-time/app/src/androidTest/java/com/sqisland/espresso/idling_resource/elapsed_time/ElapsedTimeIdlingResource.java) custom idling resource will help. (It's @chiuki code so i will not pass it here)